# Problem with splitting args (Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner to java-script and I can't figure out how to split an argument when I initiate a command.

I watched a lot of YouTube videos using the splitting argument in different forms.

When I am saying `!args` test, I should go to the "you said something next to args", but it always goes to the first line

```js
let message = { "content" : "........" }
const prefix = "...."

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

//testing args
if (command === "args") {
  if (!args[1]) {
    message.reply(" you didn't say anything next to args!");
  } else {
    message.reply(" you said something next to args!");
  }
}
console.log(message)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what ```args``` might be?

Comment: Args in this case splits the command into different words, so basically if you say
!args one two three
it would split it into a array like
[args, one, two, three]
My problem is that the command is not recognizing anything after the command.

Comment: I made a snippet. Please fill in the dots

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It is very valuable if you know how to debug a program to 
investigate the current program state. Start using the F12 tools in the browser you use for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shift()` **modifies the original array**.

It's likely that your problem is that you should be testing for args[0] instead of args[1], since you already removed the first item when `const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();` was executed.

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

//testing args
if(command === "args"){
    if(!args[0]){
        message.reply(" you didn't say anything next to args!");
    } else {
        message.reply(" you said something next to args!");
    }
}
```

Does this have your expected behavior?

Comment: YES! Oh my god thank you so much, I am such a stupid person when it comes to coding

Comment: You're welcome. You can check more info about the shift method (and others) here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp